# How to replace input type=”submit” to button on Contact Form 7?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
remove_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_shortcode_submit', 20 );<br>
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_shortcode_submit_button' );

function wpcf7_add_shortcode_submit_button() {
    wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'submit', 'wpcf7_submit_button_shortcode_handler' );
}

function wpcf7_submit_button_shortcode_handler( $tag ) {
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type );

    $atts = array();

    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'int', true );

    $value = isset( $tag->values[0] ) ? $tag->values[0] : '';
    if ( empty( $value ) )
        $value = __( 'Send', 'contact-form-7' );

    $atts['type'] = 'submit';

    $atts = wpcf7_format`enter code here`_atts( $atts );

    $html = sprintf( '<button %1$s>%2$s</button>', $atts, $value );
    enter code here
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: First, remove the HTML ``<br>`` from your PHP code. On the first line.

Answer (score 10):

**Simple solution to use your custom button as the submit button**

Just add the following two classes to your custom button or anchor tag.
`.wpcf7-form-control` and `.wpcf7-submit`

**Please find the above two classes in the example below**

```
<button type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-primary custom-btn-style">Send Message</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can place this code in functions.php

```
remove_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_submit' );
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'new_wpcf7_add_shortcode_submit_button',20 );

function new_wpcf7_add_shortcode_submit_button() {
    wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'submit', 'new_wpcf7_submit_button_shortcode_handler' );
}

function new_wpcf7_submit_button_shortcode_handler( $tag ) {
    ......
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with easier way - jQuery:

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
echo '<script>
      jQuery(\'.wpcf7-form [type="submit"]\').attr("type","button");
      </script>';
}, 9999);
```

If you want to replace that input with custom button element, then you can do so

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
echo '<script>
      jQuery(\'.wpcf7-form [type="submit"]\').hide();
      jQuery(\'<button type="submit>BUTTON</button>"\').insertAfter(jQuery(\'.wpcf7-form [type="submit"]\'));
      </script>';
}, 9999);
```

Comment: Thanks.
Not Change only input type.
I need like <button>send</button>

Comment: I have try to add button directly in form. it working with form.  
  
<button id='submit' class='wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit'>Send</button>